# Background static when using headphone with Microsoft Surface

Tags: noise, windows-rt, surface-2

I am using Microsoft Surface 2 (non-pro) tablet, and I like to use headphone with it. The problem is that whenever I plug a headphone in and I play something, I hear this statics background sound. It comes up every time an audio coming up. It is hard to explain due to my English not good. When the tablet is making any audio like musics, or the sound of mouse clicking, or the sound of windows warning alert, and something likes that. That annoying background static is coming up. But if no audio is playing, no static neither. I googled for solutions but found none useful. Can you help me?

Comment: My guess is that either there is a defective chip inside your device, or the tablet was not designed well and the audio circuitry is not protected from interference properly.

Comment: I should contact Microsoft to get a replacement then.

Comment: That's what I would suggest, yes.  Seems like you're not the only one with this issue: http://www.surfaceforums.net/threads/sp2-owners-do-you-have-a-hissing-background-static-from-the-speakers-headphones.6396/